# How to convert the image to base64 after take a photo from camera or library

Tags: ios, swift, api, swiftui, uikit

I want to make a button that when pressed will take a photo, after I take a photo I can directly convert the photo to base64 and will be used to post to the API

This is my code :)

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit


struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var selectedImage: UIImage
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode
    var sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType = .photoLibrary
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        imagePicker.sourceType = sourceType
        imagePicker.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        return imagePicker
        
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: Context) {
        //leave alone for right now
    }
    
    final class Coordinator: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
     
        var parent: ImagePicker
     
        init(_ parent: ImagePicker) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
    
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
     
            if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                parent.selectedImage = image
                
            }
            parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
        
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
}

class ImageConverter {

    func base64ToImage(_ base64String: String) -> UIImage? {
        guard let imageData = Data(base64Encoded: base64String) else { return nil }
        return UIImage(data: imageData)
    }

    func imageToBase64(_ image: UIImage) -> String? {
        return image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)?.base64EncodedString()
    }

}
```

this is some of my view, i want when i press the button it will direct me to the camera and when i take a photo it will convert it to base64 and save it in a string

```
import SwiftUI

struct ProfileView: View {
    let imageManager = ImageConverter()
    
    @State var changeProfileImage = false
    @State var openCameraRoll = false
    @State var imageSelected = UIImage()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
            Button(action: {
                changeProfileImage = true
                openCameraRoll = true
                
            }, label: {
                if changeProfileImage {
                    Image(uiImage: imageSelected)
                        .profileImageMod()
                } else {
                    Image("AddProfileImage")
                        .profileImageMod()
                }
        })
            
            Image(systemName: "plus")
                .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .background(Color.gray)
                .clipShape(Circle())
            
        }.sheet(isPresented: $openCameraRoll) {
            ImagePicker(selectedImage: $imageSelected, sourceType: .camera)
            
        }.onAppear {
            
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE** this is my Imagepicker

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit


struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var selectedImage: UIImage
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode
    var sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType = .photoLibrary
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        imagePicker.sourceType = sourceType
        imagePicker.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        return imagePicker
        
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: Context) {
        //leave alone for right now
    }
    
    final class Coordinator: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
     
        var parent: ImagePicker
     
        init(_ parent: ImagePicker) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
    
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
     
            if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                parent.selectedImage = image
                
            }
            parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
        
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
}

class ImageConverter {

    func base64ToImage(_ base64String: String) -> UIImage? {
        guard let imageData = Data(base64Encoded: base64String) else { return nil }
        return UIImage(data: imageData)
    }

    func imageToBase64(_ image: UIImage) -> String? {
        return image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)?.base64EncodedString()
    }

}
```

Comment: what have you tried so far to take a picture and convert it? There are a **lot** of info on that on SO and elsewhere. Have you done a search for this? You have the code for converting in your `ImageConverter`, what it not working there?

Comment: im sorry i put the wrong view im updating it now, for now i can take a photo or picking photo from library and my question is  i don't know how to convert the photo that i take 
to base64 with ImageConverter when i take a photo or picking it from my library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use something like this approach, using the `.onDismiss()`
to then convert your `imageSelected` to base64 string using your `ImageConverter`.

In `ProfileView`,

```
 .sheet(isPresented: $openCameraRoll, onDismiss: didDismiss) {
    ImagePicker(selectedImage: $imageSelected, sourceType: .camera)
 }
 
 func didDismiss() {
     let b64Str = imageManager.imageToBase64(imageSelected)
     print("\n---> b64Str: \(b64Str?.count) \n")
 }
```

Also remove the `ZStack`, or replace it by a `VStack`

EDIT-1: here some example code that works for me:

```
struct ProfileView: View {
    let imageManager = ImageConverter()
    
    @State var changeProfileImage = false
    @State var openCameraRoll = false
    @State var imageSelected = UIImage()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                openCameraRoll = true
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
                //  .profileImageMod()
            })
            if changeProfileImage {
                Image(uiImage: imageSelected)
                    .resizable() // <-- here
                    .frame(width: 222, height: 222)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .background(Color.gray)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
            } else {
                Image(systemName: "questionmark")
                    .frame(width: 222, height: 222)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .background(Color.gray)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $openCameraRoll, onDismiss: didDismiss) {
            ImagePicker(selectedImage: $imageSelected, sourceType: .camera)
        }
    }
    
    func didDismiss() {
        changeProfileImage = true
        let b64Str = imageManager.imageToBase64(imageSelected)
        print("\n---> b64Str: \(b64Str?.count) \n")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank youuu, it work great on me! finally now i can converting it to base64